# URLDecode Confusion

Tags: tomcat, java-web-start, urldecode

I am learning to write a front-end and back-end project using tomcat+javaweb, but after the front-end initiates a request, the back-end cannot correctly parse Chinese characters, in the front-end I encodeURI for Chinese characters, the back-end URLDecoder.decode parsing result is garbled, the front-end and back-end character sets are utf-8.

I tried to get the correct Chinese characters in the test function by parsing the URL encoding directly from tomcat, and I hope to get the correct Chinese characters in the tomcat service.